Live Server executable in Python
I'm trying to create an executable that mimics the Live Server VSCode extension. I created a local web app and my colleagues should be able to use it without having to install python or VS Code.
This short code works well if I run python server.py
import http.server  
import socketserver  
import webbrowser  
PORT = 8000  

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler  

# Start the server  
with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:  
    print(f"Server started at http://localhost:{PORT}")  

    # Open the web browser  
    webbrowser.open_new_tab(f"http://localhost:{PORT}/main.html")  

    # Serve the HTML file  
    httpd.serve_forever()

But after compiling with pyinstaller, the server.exe file has the problem that updating any of the html/css/js files takes no effect (even after closing and reopening server.exe).
It seems as if everything is wrapped inside the executable.
I need a solution that allows me to add new data daily without having to recompile it each time.
file structure
